# How to plot as shown in attached figure in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, data, plot-themes, inset

How do I produce such kind of appearance of graphs in mathematica where in the bottom panel i show the ratio of the comparison (like numerical/analytical estimate) and in top model I show the numerical and analytical results themselves ?
N>B. : The figure is for representative purpose.

[image]

Comment: You asked this question very timely. Just yesterday I started looking for an answer to such a question and found this document. I hope he helps you and we hope that users will provide support.

[SciDraw.Publication-quality scientific figures with Mathematica.A user's guide and reference manual](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8958/SciDrawGuide.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps you can use [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53736363#53736363)

Answer (score 2):

When I want to have two plots with the same x-axis arranged vertically, I usually use `Column`. The trick is to force the 2 plots to have the same left and right `ImagePadding`, 0 padding at the bottom of the top plot, 0 padding at the top of the bottom plot, and to set the `Spacings` to 0.

```
Column[{
  Plot[
   x^2,
   {x, 0, 5},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True,
   ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {0, Automatic}},
   ImageSize -> 400
   ],
  Plot[
   x,
   {x, 0, 5},
   AspectRatio -> 1/3,
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True,
   ImagePadding -> {{20, 5}, {Automatic, 0}},
   ImageSize -> 400
   ]
  },
 Spacings -> 0
]
```

[image: Combined plot.]